# i'm getting error while inserting data into MS SQL Server using php

Tags: php, html, sql-server

MS SQL SERVER table

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [mob] [sms] FROM [SMS].[dbo].[data]
```

This is my php script

```
<?php

$mob = $_POST['mob'];
$smss = $_POST['sms'];



$serverName="DESKTOP-471VOGK\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo=array("Database"=>"SMS.MDF");
$conn= sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);



 //connect to sql


  // Input into staff database
  $sql = "INSERT INTO data (mob,sms) VALUES (?,?)";


 $params = array($mob,$smss);
 $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
 if( $stmt === false ) {
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }
else {

echo "Sucess";

}

?>
```

i'm getting error as

> Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\sms.php on line 22
>   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )

please help me.

Comment: I would guess your connection failed. Can I suggest you do some error checking in your code

Comment: [See example 1 in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) and add the suggested error checking

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes its due to connection error.

Comment: Look [at example 2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) you probably need a Uid and pwd

Comment: @RiggsFolly : Thank you.